# Dynamic Metro style UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, user-experience

Using HTML, CSS, jQuery, is it possible to create a metro style UI, which allows the user to drag each square or rectangle around the screen and while dragging, the other squares/rectangles on the screen automatically move themselves making space for the element being moved?

I know how to do this partially, if the elements being moved have the same width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will want to try [Gridster](http://gridster.net)!